# AutoHotKey: Pressing two keys simultaneously without repeats

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, script, macros, autohotkey

Is there a way to press two keys simultaneously and bind it to a macro key (for example, pressing "s" and "d" simultaneously and then bind it to "a" key) without it having the "s" repeat multiple times when a is pressed?

Another example -
I wrote the script in AutoHotKey as:

```
a::  
SendInput {s down}{d down}{s up}{d up}  
return
```

And when I test the script in Notepad, it shows the "s" being repeated multiple times with one click of "a"

Is there a way for "s" and "d" to be pressed simultaneously without having it to repeat but will stay enabled as long as "a" is pressed with no delays? Or is there a way to fix the script so that "s" and "d" can be pressed simultaneously without it being spammed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

thsdt test script works for me sdll the time i press sd key.  sdbcdefghij. sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd if i hold down sd (errr... the A key).

If you want the holdoff for the key repeat to be slower so your system takes longer to start repeating after you hold down a key, adjust your keyboard settings in control panel.  At some point however the keys will start to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

it is not a good practice to Create ShortCut of such keys, instead of these you can use/Create some unusual shortcut like....    CapsLock and any other keys of keyboard, eg...

```
    CapsLock & s::

    CapsLock & d::
```

or You Can Create Shortcut with Hold Mouse Right Click and Press any other Key from Keyboard.... eg...

```
    ~RButton & s::

    ~LButton & d::

    ~MButton & s::
```

You can use any key combinations... with mouse clicks....

Hope You Got my Point....

and another way of Creating ShortCut ... is like that..... you can create shortcuts with Right Control....   eg....

```
    >^s::                ; this means Right Control and s .....


    >!d::                ; this means Right Alt and d .....
```

and so on...

Hope you Got it .....

Enjoy the world of Shortcut with AutoHotKey... GoodBye.